# Integral inequality in a probabilty space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space.

Let $v \in \mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$.

Show that $|\int_X v \, d\mu | \leq ||v||$.

$||v||$ denotes the uniform norm.

I know the following but would like some help to connect it with the uniform norm given by $ ||v|| = \sup \lbrace |v(x)| : x \in X \rbrace $

$|\int_X v \, d\mu | \leq \int_X |v| \, d\mu  $.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27923/290189) to avoid asking problem statement questions (PSQ).

Comment: What is the uniform norm in this context?

Comment: I updated the question with the definition

Comment: hint: $\mu(X)=1.$

Comment: I am aware of that, but I'm not sure what to do with that fact.

Answer (score 0):

With $\|v\| =\sup \lbrace |v(x)| : x \in X \rbrace,$ calculate

$|\int_X v \, d\mu | \leq \int_X|v|d\mu\le \int_X\|v\| d\mu=$

$\|v\|\int_Xd\mu=\|v\|\cdot \mu (X)=\|v\|\cdot 1=\|v\|.$